# Dropwizard IO Metrics are always aggregated

Tags: aggregate, aggregation, dropwizard, metrics

I'm trying to monitor some metrics via [Dropwizard IO Metrics](http://metrics.dropwizard.io/3.1.0/). I want to get number of files downloaded in a specific time period, and I want to aggregate that metric by myself. So for example, let's say between *10.00 to 10.15*, **60** files are downloaded. I want the metric to be **60** between this period and after *10.15*, it must return **zero**. However, after *10.15*, the metric always returns 60. Is there a way to avoid its automatic aggregation?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, you are just using the wrong metric I assume. You will have to use a metric that uses time windows and configure them correctly. Look at this simple example I wrote up:

```
public class MetricTest {

    public static final long SLEEP_TIME = 51;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        SlidingTimeWindowReservoir reservoir = new SlidingTimeWindowReservoir(50, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        Histogram h = new Histogram(reservoir);

        h.update(1);
        System.out.println(h.getSnapshot().size());
        Thread.sleep(SLEEP_TIME);

        h.update(1);
        System.out.println(h.getSnapshot().size());
        Thread.sleep(SLEEP_TIME);

        h.update(1);
        System.out.println(h.getSnapshot().size());
        Thread.sleep(SLEEP_TIME);

        h.update(1);
        System.out.println(h.getSnapshot().size());
        Thread.sleep(SLEEP_TIME);

        h.update(1);
        System.out.println(h.getSnapshot().size());
        Thread.sleep(SLEEP_TIME);

        h.update(1);
        System.out.println(h.getSnapshot().size());

    }
}
```

I am using a histogram to count the amount of values I submitted. See the SLEEP_TIME constant above for expiry.

If I run this with a sleep time of 0, i get:

> 1 2 3 4 5 6

If I run it with a sleep time of 51, the previous value is expired each time a snapshot is created, and I get:

> 1 1 1 1 1 1

You can write your own window implementation that simply does bucketing and deletes old buckets.

I hope that clarifies how metrics work.

Artur

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I know this usage, however as far as I tried, it cannot be applied to counter; and using a histogram instead of a simple counter will be too complex. Is there anything I can use with counter (like a reset thing)?

Comment: You can extend counter and implement the bucket logic yourself. What you want to use however is a histogram (distribution over time), not a count. A count by definition is what it says: a counter :) So that is why it has no logic to reset it. You can also look into Timers, which are meters that also support sliding windows.